# Error: Incorrect Configuration while using Tango Explorer or any Tango enabled app (dalvik v/s ART)

Tags: unity-game-engine, dalvik, google-project-tango

I'm **suddenly** getting this error while running any Tango enabled app (Google's Tango Explorer app etc..or my own build):
`Error: Incorrect Configuration. Please go to Settings-->Developer options and use ART`

By default the device came with `dalvik` & was running fine. 
I've read some [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/25qlut/psa_dont_use_the_art_runtime_and_expect_your/) pointing the issues with using `ART`.

Still I switched to 'ART' and after rebooting the tablet, all the apps that were installed before changing to ART works fine(tango capabilities) but if I install a new tango-enabled app its not able to access tango core and throws an error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Lenovo devices or Tango Dev kits?

If you are using Tango Dev Kits you need to switch to ART.
although for KitKat, ART is not default runtime,
Tango Dev kits have performance issues on running on Dalvik.
It will have drops frames and other issues.
That is why Tango UX remind you that you need to run on ART.
Please switch back to ART runtime.

For Lenovo devices since it is on Android M it should be on ART already.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I'm using Tango Dev Kit. I have 2 Tango Dev kits, one have Dalvik and other have ART and surprisingly enough both works fine. By default both came with Dalvik, after some time one kit started giving the issue and I had to switch to ART.